# pprint in browser repl causes TypeError

Tags: clojurescript, boot-clj

Does anybody understand the following behavior inside a ClojureScript browser repl? (provided by the boot tool chain)

```
my.core> (require 'cljs.pprint)
nil
my.core> (cljs.pprint/pprint "one")
#object[TypeError TypeError: cljs.pprint is undefined]
No stacktrace available.
my.core> (cljs.pprint/pprint "one" "two" "three")
WARNING: Wrong number of args (3) passed to cljs.pprint/pprint at line 1 <cljs repl>
#object[TypeError TypeError: cljs.pprint is undefined]
No stacktrace available.
```

It looks, that there is no reference to cljs.pprint/pprint, however the repl knows about the arity of this function.

---

this might help as well:

```
my.core> (cljs.repl/dir cljs.pprint)
t_cljs$pprint28171
t_cljs$pprint28177
with-pprint-dispatch
with-pretty-writer
write
write-out
nil
```

Answer (score 3):

`cider-repl-toggle-pretty-printing` did the trick.